# How to build a multitrack file using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have four audio files, each containing a stereo program (two tracks). What I want to do is combine them into one file containing 8 tracks. I've tried several different ffmpeg commands but the best I've been able to do is merge the tracks into one track, which is not what I want. Is this possible? Can you even have an audio file with 8 tracks? If so, what file formats support this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As the bot has said I am not 100% what you are looking for here.

Comment: Is it so that all 8 tracks play at once, or so you can switch between the different tracks in the same file.  An example of this might be you have a film with sound tracks in different languages so you can switch to your language, then you would include X number of tracks.

Comment: Our goal is to upload the file to a transcription service which supports multiple channels, this is why we are trying to build this kind of a file. The transcription service is built to handle conversations where each person speaking is using a different microphone recorded on a separate channel.

Comment: So, yes, in a sense I want all 8 tracks to play simlutaneously if the recording were played, but it's ultimately not going to be played that way, it's going to be submitted to a transcription service which will listen to each track separately.